# How could I convert jsx into coffeescript and get it work with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, reactjs

It is painful to deal with lots of nested parenthesis with JavaScripts. So, how could I convert this file `sample.js.jsx` into CoffeeScript and get it work under Ruby on Rails?

I'm working with the gem `react-rails`

## sample code

```
function getNewSymptomLayer(index) {
    return {
        index: index,
        layer1: "",
        layer2: [],
        layer3: []
    }
}
function SymptonsDataStore() {
    this.symptom = [];
    this.callback = [];
}

....

var SearchBar = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
          data: dataStore.getCurrentState(),
          mainSymptomCode: ''
        };
    },
    stateChange: function () {
        this.setState({data: dataStore.getCurrentState()});
    },
    removeRow: function (index, evt) {
        this.symptom.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({data: symptoms});
    },
    render: function () {
        var sym = this.state.data.map(function (indexOfSymptoms, index) {
            return (<Symptom key={index} data={indexOfSymptoms}/>);
        });
        dataStore.register(this.stateChange);
        var add = function () {
            dataStore.addRow();
        };
        return <div>{sym}
            <span onClick={add}>+</span>
        </div>;
    }
});
React.render(<SearchBar data={dataStore.getCurrentState()}/>, document.getElementById("sym"));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a [js2coffee](http://js2.coffee) converter. Paste your js code here and save the file with `.js.cjsx` extension (coffee-jsx). You need to temporary wrap jsx with quotes.

Secondly, you need to install gem '[sprockets-coffee-react](https://github.com/jsdf/sprockets-coffee-react)'. It will do the job for the rest things (assets, sprockets and so on)

Comment: js2coffee dosen't work, i think it doesn't recognize JSX. i'll try the next one you mentioned

Comment: Right! I've updated the answer. You need to temporary wrap your jsx into quotes, like: `<span onClick={add}>+</span>` to `"<span onClick={add}>+</span>"`. You need to remove these quotes after converting and copy-pasting